# PHP data passed as string instead of integer

Tags: php, javascript

I have a slight issue with parsing data in an array from PHP to JavaScript.

My JavaScript is thinking the data is a string and not an integer. Resulting in the wrong answer with the maths.

My JS maths is this:

```
abposx = data[d]["x"]+offset_x;
```

If data[d]["x"] was 20 and offset_x  was 0

The answer becomes 200 instead of 20.

I'm wondering how I can get JavaScript to use data[d]["x"] as an number and not a string?

This jist of my php:

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT x,y,sid FROM $table WHERE uid='1'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
$data = json_encode($data);
```

The json Encode looks like this:

```
[{"x":"283","y":"99","sid":"1"}]
```

Hope you can help!

Comment: Can't you just cast it as an int? `(int)data[d]["x"]+offset_x;`

Comment: Could you post the PHP where you set the value? Are you using ajax?

Comment: No, i tried that but i got Unexpected identifier as an error.

Comment: Yes both produce Unexpected identifier error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
abposx = parseInt(data[d]["x"], 10) + offset_x;
```

Comment: can you inspect the value of `data[d]["x"]`? What is it? Unless it is not a number, this code should work.

Comment: Glad to know there is no miracle in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

parseInt can be used javascriptside, if you want do this phpside use as;

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
    $data[] = array_map('intval',$row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using type conversion:

```
var absData = data[d]["x"] - 0;
abposx = absData+offset_x;
```

Comment: This should be JavaScript code, there is no typecasting in JavaScript, nor `int` type...

Answer (score 0):

use parseInt(string), which returns the string as an integer

Comment: Don't forget the radix, `parseInt(string, 10)`